# Ajax return multiple values

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I'm trying to return multiple values as shown below but one value is only returning on success.

This is what I'm trying to do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#getdetails").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/Gettext",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ SampleText: $('#sampletext').val(), FontType: $('#fonttype').val()}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                    }
                });

        $("#FontLists").change(function () {
            $('#fonttype').val($('#FontLists option:selected').text());
        });
    });
</Script>
```

HTML:

```
Enter Text :<input id="sampletext" type="text" />
<select id="FontLists">
    <option value="Aharoni">Aharoni</option>
    <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
    <option value="Andalus">Andalus</option>
</select>
<input id="fonttype" type="hidden" />
```

Codebehind:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Shared Function Gettext(ByVal SampleText As String, ByVal FontType As String) As String
    Return SampleText
    Return FontType
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could design a class with 2 properties and then have your WebMethod return an instance of this class (sorry if I made some typos, my VB.NET skills are rusty).

```
Public Class MyModel
    Public Property SampleText as String
    Public Property FontType as FontType
End Class
```

and then adapt your method to return this model:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Shared Function Gettext(ByVal SampleText As String, ByVal FontType As String) As MyModel
    Dim model = New MyModel()
    model.SampleText = SampleText
    model.FontType = FontType
    Return model
End Function
```

and on the client you could access the 2 properties using their names:

```
success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg.d.SampleText);
    alert(msg.d.FontType);
}
```

Comment: And one simple question instead of producing alerts how do I combine and display as  $("#Result").text(msg.d[0].WatermarkText, msg.d[1].FontType);